# MS Access Criteria Query, Filter results Less than the Current Date and Specific Time

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I have a table with a DateCreated field under this ex. format, in MS Access I'd like to filter our the results to show only the entries which satisfies the condition:

All entries that were created prior to the CURRENT date @ 3:00pm

```
DateCreated
2/02/2017 8:33:07 AM
13/01/2017 4:00:54 PM
19/02/2017 7:49:59 AM
17/02/2017 9:04:47 PM
19/02/2017 6:21:32 PM
19/02/2017 9:00:47 AM
20/02/2017 10:32:32 AM
1/02/2017 7:48:06 PM
19/02/2017 12:30:25 PM
20/02/2017 12:24:59 PM
20/02/2017 12:44:53 PM
20/02/2017 10:57:28 AM
19/02/2017 7:00:38 PM
```

I would appreciate for any answers/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GUI designer, use this criteria for `DateCreated`:

```
<DateAdd("h",15,Date())
```